# Retrieve Curl Information json_decode

Tags: php, json

I connected to an e-commerce application via the following on the command line:

```
 curl -u xxxxxx: https://xxxx/xxx
```

It returns something like this:

```
{ "charge_enabled": true, 
  "details_submitted": true, 
  "email": "xxx@gmail.com", 
  "id": "xxxx", 
  "statement_descriptor": "xxxx", 
  "xxxx": [ "USD" ] 
}
```

When I change this to PHP to run this in a script, I also can retrieve the same info via the following:

```
 $ch = curl_init('https://xxxx/xxxx');
 $options = array(        
  CURLOPT_USERPWD=> $xxxxxx
   );
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
  $result2= curl_exec($ch);
```

However, when I try to retrieve the individual information like the email, I am unable to do so. I try to do so via `json_decode` as follows:

```
 $parsedresult = json_decode($result2,true);
 $emailretrieve = $parsedresult["email"];
```

This returns only the single number `1` and not the email address.

Can anyone help and tell me what's wrong? I tried many things already posted here on StackOverflow and got none of them to work.

Comment: Can you show what exactly `$result2` contains? What does `print_r($parsedresult)` give you?

Comment: echo-debugging always works nicely: `var_dump($result2, $parsedresult, $emailretrieve);` - what do you get?

Comment: $result2 automatically print out the following, without me echoing.: { "charge_enabled": true, "details_submitted": true, "email": "xxx@gmail.com", "id": "xxxx", "statement_descriptor": "xxxx", "xxxx": [ "USD" ] }. print_r($parsedresult) returns the number 1. It print out 1.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` (mentioned in http://php.net/curl_exec) to fetch the result. Right now, you only get "successful" or "failed" as result.

Comment: @Nochbag: Do you see how we analysed the problem and tracked it down? var_dump() variables in question and ask yourself "Does the value make sense? Is it expected?" and if you answer with no, open the manual and start reading there. Oh, and if you accept the answer for yourself, please do so on Stack Overflow as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Nochbag Any particular reason for not accepting this answer? It's just that others may find it helpful when they know what worked, and what didn't.